# Relation between independence and correlation of uniform random variables

Tags: correlation, independence, uniform-distribution

My question is fairly simple: let $X$ and $Y$ be two uncorrelated uniform random variables on $[-1,1]$. Are they independent?

I was under the impression that two random, uncorrelated variables are only necessarily independent if their joint distribution is normal. However, I can't come up with a counterexample to disprove the claim I am asking about. Please provide either a counterexample or a proof.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Independent implies uncorrelated but the implication doesn't go the other way.

Uncorrelated implies independence only under certain conditions. e.g. if you have a *bivariate normal*, it is the case that uncorrelated implies independent (as you said).

It is easy to construct bivariate distributions with uniform margins where the variables are uncorrelated but are not independent. Here are a few examples:

1. consider an additional random variable $B$ which takes the values $\pm 1$ each with probability $\frac12$, independent of $X$. Then let $Y=BX$.
2. take the bivariate distribution of two independent uniforms and slice it in 4 equal-size sections on each margin (yielding $4\times 4=16$ pieces, each of size $\frac12\times\frac12$). Now take all the probability from the 4 corner pieces and the 4 center pieces and put it evenly into the other 8 pieces.
3. Let $Y = 2|X|-1$.

In each case, the variables are uncorrelated but not independent (e.g. if $X=1$, what is $P(-0.1<Y<0.1)\,$?)

[image: Plot of bivariate distribution for each case]

If you specify some particular family of bivariate distributions with uniform margins it might be possible that *under that formulation* the only uncorrelated one is independent. Then being uncorrelated would imply independence.

For example, if you restrict your attention to say the Gaussian copula, then I think the only uncorrelated one has independent margins; you can readily rescale that so that each margin is on (-1,1).

---

Some R code for sampling from and plotting these bivariates (not necessarily efficiently):

```r
    n <- 100000
    x <- runif(n,-1,1)
    b <- rbinom(n,1,.5)*2-1
    y1 <-b*x
    y2 <-ifelse(0.5<abs(x)&abs(x)<1,
           runif(n,-.5,.5),
           runif(n,0.5,1)*b
          )
    y3 <- 2*abs(x)-1

    par(mfrow=c(1,3))
    plot(x,y1,pch=16,cex=.3,col=rgb(.5,.5,.5,.5))
    plot(x,y2,pch=16,cex=.5,col=rgb(.5,.5,.5,.5))
    abline(h=c(-1,-.5,0,.5,1),col=4,lty=3)
    abline(v=c(-1,-.5,0,.5,1),col=4,lty=3)
    plot(x,y3,pch=16,cex=.3,col=rgb(.5,.5,.5,.5))
```

(In this formulation, $(Y_2, Y_3)$ gives a fourth example)

[Incidentally by transforming all of these to normality (i.e. transforming $X$ to $\Phi^{-1}(\frac12(X+1))$ and so forth), you get examples of uncorrelated normal random variables that are not independent. Naturally they aren't jointly normal.]

Comment: Thank you. I'm struggling to see why the examples you provided still guarantee that $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1, 1]$, though.

Comment: Do the plots of the bivariate densities help? In each case the shaded parts are all of constant density

Comment: They make it visually clearer, yes. Thank you, again.