Is it possible for two normally distributed (ideally nondegenerate) random variables with 0 covariance to not be independent?
I know if the variables are jointly normal, 0 covariance implies independence, and I know that marginal normal distributions don't imply a joint normal distribution, but is there a way for the covariances of the normal distributions to be 0 and not have a bivariate normal/not be independent? I can't think of a reason why not but I wasn't sure how to go about constructing one.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467071/the-joint-density-of-two-dependent-yet-uncorrelated-normal-variables/644938#644938

There's two examples here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565810/805 (one degenerate, one not); the degenerate one can be made nondegenerate by adding a small amount of independent Gaussian noise to each variable ... you can also take the center example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/398057/805 and transform each uniform variable to a standard normal, for another nondegenerate example.  There are a good number of others to be found on site.

thank you! i don't know how i missed that post
